# How can I import EclipseLink source code successfully from the GIT repository into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipselink, m2eclipse

So I checked out the code of EclipseLink from this repository:
http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git

After that I did: File -> Import -> Existing Maven Projects -> browse to C:\Users\amosomar\git\eclipselink.runtime\buildsystem\org.eclipse.persistence.parent and imported all the projects that showed up.

[image: import]

Then I get the following error:

**An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
Path must include project and resource name: /org.eclipse.persistence.nosql**

[image]

It also happens when I do:
Right click on one of the projects -> Maven -> Update Project

**An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
Path must include project and resource name: /org.eclipse.persistence.core**
[image]

I have tried this with `JBoss Devloper Studio 7.0.0 GA` and `Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0 RELEASE` without success both have `m2eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317` installed.

It seems to have something to do with the parent project `"org.eclipse.persistence.parent"`  and the modules because if I remove for example from project `"org.eclipse.persistence.core"` pom the reference to the parent the problem goes away:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
             <relativePath>../../buildsystem/org.eclipse.persistence.parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```